# Form submit with HTTP-POST causes CORS error

Tags: javascript, html, cors, semantic-ui

There is a backend written in C++, which handles HTTP requests (using JSON).
The frontend is using semantic ui, but ajax is used for sending the request:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
function createProjectJson(projectName) {
    var ret = JSON.stringify({
        project: {
            identity: {
                name: projectName
            }
        }
    })
    return ret;
}

var endpoints = {
    'createProject': 'http://127.0.0.1:1912/api/projects'
}

$('form .submit.button').click(function (event) {
    var proName = $("#createPro").val();
    if(proName.length === 0)
        event.preventDefault();
    else
    {
        var payload = createProjectJson(proName);

        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url: endpoints.createProject,
            data: payload,
            method: "POST"
        }).done(function( json ) {
            console.log("done");
         })
         .fail(function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
           console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
           console.log( "Status: " + status );
           console.dir( xhr );
         });
    }
});
});
```

The form looks like this:

```
 <form class="ui form">
        <div class="field">
            <label>Project name</label>
            <div class="field">
                <input id="createPro" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Give the project a name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="hidden">
            <label>Project enabled</label>
        </div>
        <div class="ui submit button">Create</div>
    </form>
```

According to [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests), there should be no CORS triggered. Why do I get this error:
[image: request]
[image: console output]

The webserver is running on 172.0.0.1:5500 (I'm using live server plugin in VS code).
I've implemented CORS on the backend as well (echoing the origin in the CORS response) on a PUT, with the same error. I tried to use * (in Access-Control-Allow-Origin) in the CORS response, same result.
The server response data is just an empty `{}`.
Furthermore I checked the backend (no OPTIONS req) and wireshark did not show any other packages as the POST + response.

Comment: Yes. It will throw CORS Error. You need to ask your backend server guys to whitelist your ip so you can make requests from your ip. If you ip changes frequently, then it is better to whitelist all ips request(security threat involved)

Comment: All the best. If you solve let me know the solution you worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. According to the spec, there should be CORS request, just not preflight request.
2. Code is running in `http://127.0.0.1:1912` while the resource is in `http://127.0.0.1:5500`. Different ports means different Origins, hence this is a CORS request.
3. In the screenshot you provided there's no Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the response header. You should add one to resolve the issue.

Comment: That's embarrassing. I didn't read the spec properly...
So, every request coming from a different addr, needs to have the header set? I only did it for the options reqs.
CORS is the greatest sh*t. The server should handle wrong reqs. and not the client. I do not need a browser to sent reqs. XD
Whatever, thank you very much.